# How to make ajax request from django forms and load response data back

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Here is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from category.models import *

class ItemForm(forms.Form):

    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('category_text'),label=_("Category"))
    subcategory = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subcategory.objects.all().order_by('subcategory_text'),label=_("Subcategory"))
    item = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30, render_value=False)), label=_("Item")
```

Here is models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    category_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_text


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    subcategory_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subcategory_text
```

I want to select `category` from `dropdown` first then based on `category` all the `subcategory` under that `category` I want to load under `Subcategory` `dropdown .

I don't how I can make `ajax` `request` from `django form` and load response data back to the `dropdown` in `form`.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Your ajax call (client side) will be put in the template and server side in in the view   see http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/ajax.html for good example

Comment: How I can control the template, as the form is getting generated from `forms.py `

Comment: take also look at this https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/